# Using JavaScript if/else function to return an image

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying to use JavaScript functions to return an image. I want the user to input "Art" or "Travel", and then have one of two images returned, depending on their input. I'm NOT a programmer, this is something I'm trying to do for one of my basic tech classes, so I'm really quite the noob and to be honest don't understand some of the jargon that I've read in other answer. If anyone could spell out what I'm doing wrong for me in simple terms, I'd really appreciate it. This is the code I have written: It keeps telling me that there is an Uncaught SyntaxError with the return portion, and it's telling me that my function is not defined.

Thanks!

```
<h3>Please indicate whether you would like to see a collage of art that I have made, or a collage of pictures made of places I have visited (please type "Art" or "Travel"):</h3>

<input id="answer"> <!---start of first function (html)-->

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

<!--end of first function (html)--> 

<script> <!---start of first function (javascript)--> 
function myFunction() {
    var x, text;

    x = document.getElementById("answer").value;

    if (x == Art) { 
        return <a href="http://imgur.com/21cHFIU"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/21cHFIU.png" title="source: imgur.com" /></a>
    }else  {
        return <a href="http://imgur.com/3UFIhPG"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/3UFIhPG.png" title="source: imgur.com" /></a>

    }


}
</script> <!---end of first function (javascript)-->
```

Comment: I think you mean `if(x == 'Art')`

Comment: ... and `return  '<a....>';` not `return <a...>;`

Comment: Also, return statement should return a string

Comment: Can you please provide a little more info of what your desired result when clicking  the button?

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a string and then render it, you are currently returning invalid syntax.

Another option would be to have the img tag in your markup and change the src attribute on submit of the button.

```
<h3>Please indicate whether you would like to see a collage of art that I have made, or a collage of pictures made of places I have visited (please type "Art" or "Travel"):</h3>

<input id="answer"> <!---start of first function (html)-->

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
<img id="image" src="" title="source: imgur.com" />
<!--end of first function (html)--> 

<script> <!---start of first function (javascript)--> 
function myFunction() {
    var image = document.getElementById("image");
    var answer = document.getElementById("answer").value;

    if (answer === "Art") { 
        image.src = "http://imgur.com/21cHFIU";
    } else if (answer === "Travel") {
        image.src = "http://imgur.com/3UFIhPG";
    }
}
</script> <!---end of first function (javascript)-->
```

Answer (score 0):

The comment below is not in Javascript comment syntax:

`<script> <!---start of first function (javascript)-->`

While inside the script tag, you have to use comments like this:

`//start of first function (javascript)`

Instead of:

`if (x == Art)`

You have to use quotes since `Art` is a string, not a Javascript keyword. Do this instead:

`if (x == "Art")`

You are returning a non Javascript variable here:

`return <a href="http://imgur.com/21cHFIU"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/21cHFIU.png" title="source: imgur.com" /></a>`

So you have to use quotes like this:

`return '<a href="http://imgur.com/21cHFIU"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/21cHFIU.png" title="source: imgur.com" />'</a>`

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
<h3>Please indicate whether you would like to see a collage of art that I have made, or a collage of pictures made of places I have visited (please type "Art" or "Travel"):</h3>
<input id="answer">
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
<img id="image" src="" />

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("answer").value;
    var image = document.getElementById("image");

    if (x == 'Art') { 
        image.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/21cHFIU.png';
    }else  {
        image.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/3UFIhPG.png';
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's try to explain to you what was wrong with your code.

1 - Here, you're supposed to compare a `string` with a text. So you need to tell that *Art* is text by writing in quotes: `'Art'`.

```
if (x == Art) {
```

2 -  You shouldn't return text to a button event. That being said, there are some problems with the `string` you're trying to return from this `function`. This was the cause of the `Uncaught SyntaxError` you were getting. So the correct approach for this would be:

```
'<a href="http://imgur.com/21cHFIU"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/21cHFIU.png" title="source: imgur.com" /></a>'
```

3 - Finally, your function was not defined, cause the `<script>` tag must be wrapped in the `<head>` or `<body>` tags. Preferably right before it's respective closing tag.

I have corrected these issues and made some changes for it to work. You can check it below by clicking *Run code snippet* button.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var img = document.getElementById('img');
  var answer = document.getElementById('answer').value.toLowerCase();

  if (answer != 'art' && answer != 'travel') { //check if user input is "art" or "travel"
    alert('Please, type "Art" or "Travel"');
  } else {
    if (answer == 'art') {
      img.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/21cHFIU.png';
    } else {
      img.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/3UFIhPG.png';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h3>Please indicate whether you would like to see a collage of art that I have made, or a collage of pictures made of places I have visited (please type "Art" or "Travel"):</h3>
<input id="answer">
<!---start of first function (html)-->
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
<br /><br /><br />
<image id="img" src="" />
```